# App created with vue initi throws error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I just started using vue js and I was following a tutorial. To get started I type in the command line the following:

```
vue init webpack test-app
```

I insert the project title, author, I don't install the lint and the test framework.
I enter the project folder and run npm install and npm run dev but I get this error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                            4:58:04 PM

 error  in ./src/App.vue

Syntax Error: Unexpected token {

 @ ./~/vue-style-loader!./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"id":"data-v-17d125bb","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue 4:14-303 13:3-17:5 14:22-311
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/components/Hello.vue

Syntax Error: Unexpected token {


 @ ./~/vue-style-loader!./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"id":"data-v-369af42f","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/Hello.vue 4:14-313 13:3-17:5 14:22-321
 @ ./src/components/Hello.vue
 @ ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js

> Listening at http://localhost:8080
```

And if I go to localhost:8080 I can only see:

```
Cannot GET /
```

What can be wrong in the code with a fresh intallation?

EDIT: this is App.vue file

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <hello></hello>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Hello from './components/Hello'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Hello
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I'd guess there's an `Unexpected token {` `in ./src/App.vue`

Comment: It's the first time that I use vue, and in app.vue everything looks fine. I did not touch any file, it's a brand new installation, that's why it feels weird to me...

Comment: hmm I repeated your steps and it worked for me.

Comment: Can you tell me which version of npm/vue are you using?

Comment: vue 2.5.1; npm 3.10.9

Comment: after updating npm still the same result...
vue 2.8.1 and npm 4.1.2

Comment: Does your app maybe placed under the Dropbox directory or something similar ? Btw what nodejs version you are running ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the exact same problem! I solved it by updating Node.js to the latest version (7.7.4).

Comment: That was the problem! I had the latest version on node (installed through homebrew) but for some reasons I keep running an old version of it (4.4.1). I removed node and reinstalled it with n and everything works now!